# Where are VSCode pinned tabs stored? (workspace is loaded but not the pinned tab)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have reloaded my workspace after having move one of its parent folder. I got the workspace folders back but my pinned tab are gone.

How can I find them? Where are their path stored?

Version 1.55.2